# Parse form to JSON object using JQuery and considering sub – JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to extract from data  for submitting it , for this I have used jquery  serializeArray() function  . Which  works very nicely and gives output as  array of { name : value }  object .  This name is  similar as what I have given in form  for each element . But  I want few fields(names) in side sub document . For an example

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="login">
    <label for="_user_name">username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="_user_name" name="user.name" value="dev.pus" />
    <label for="_user_pass">password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="_user_pass" name="user.pass" value="1234" />
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var docFormParams = $("form.login"),
         docData = docFormParams.serializeArray();


var finalJson ={};

 for (var i = 0; i < docData.length; i++) {
     finalJson[docData[i].name] = docData[i].value;

 }

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(finalJson)));
```

**Output**

```
[object Object] {
  user.name: "dev.pus",
  user.pass: "1234"
}
finalJson
[object Object] {
  user.name: "dev.pus",
  user.pass: "1234"
}
finalJson.user
undefined
[object Object] {
  user.name: "dev.pus",
  user.pass: "1234"
}
```

**Output which I want :**

```
{
user :{name :"dev.pus",
       pass :"1234"

      }    
}
```

As you can see i have tried putting dot in name , but it doesn't work . Any approach to fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("form.login").serializeArray();
```

will return an array:

```
[{"name":"user.name","value":"dev.pus"},{"name":"user.pass","value":"1234"}]
```

You should "split" "name" of each element, or change "name" at inputs.
Example with "split": http://jsfiddle.net/n1su1q0h/

Answer (score 0):

Try simply constructing a Javascript object by pulling the values out of the form. Then you can serialize it:

```
obj = { "user": { "name": $('#_user_name').val(),
                  "pass": $('#_user_pass').val()
                }
      };
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```